# Ok to run form1.Show() before Application.Run(form1)?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is there anything fundamentally problematic about showing the main form, form1, before executing Application.Run(form1) ?  Like this:

```
form1.Show();
//
//some other code runs here
//
Application.Run(form1);
```

When I do this, everything appears to function normally as far as I can tell, and it gives me the behavior that I need, but I'm wondering if there might be any weirdness that it could create, and/or if it's bad practice to do this.

Comment: Not really.  You'll see the window but it is not responsive to keyboard and mouse input while // some other code runs.  Only misleading to the user if it takes more than 6 seconds and the hourglass cursor disappears, you'd then consider a splash screen.

Comment: In relation to `Application.Run()`, the new ApplicationContext just sets the Form (it's `MainForm`) to `.Visible = true;`, the same thing that `.Show()` does, then starts the non-modal Message Loop. You're settings `form1.Visible = true` twice :) (and something else related to `SetWindowPos()`)

Comment: @HansPassant - thx, yeah I have another form showing at that time, and the purpose of showing form1 first is just so that the other form has context since the app is just starting up.  Interaction will only be with the other form at that point, and then as soon as that other form is closed, Application.Run(form1) is called. Gives me what I need, but feels a touch weird to do.